# GTK : Any way to mximize the window on Button trigger

Tags: c++, gtk

Is there any callback function, so that when I click a button the window maximizes. By the way I'm using GTK 3.0 and C++ (Not gtkmm). I wrote a function which is called during the button click event and put this line

```
int maximise(){
gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}
```

It gets compiled, but while I click the button the program terminates showing segmentation fault.
(This function is inside the class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the callback is called using i.e. *g_print*

Make sure that signal is correctly connected to the button

```
g_signal_connect (button, "clicked",
              G_CALLBACK (maximise), NULL);
```

And that window is *GtkWidget* * type

Note that as it was written [GtkButton reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) the callback have to look like that:

```
void user_function (GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
```

and you have type of callback int

For me both versions (with int and void callback works)